# IMFSinkWriter can't export a large size video of mp4

Tags: c++, windows, video, mfc, ms-media-foundation

My Windows MFC application has a function to export a video file.
And it can select encoding format (via **WMV** or **MP4**) and frame size.
But, Unfortunately when i tried to export **MP4** file which is set large frame size, everytime **MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE** happened.

Simply put, here is the result when i tested in each case.

### WMV

- 640 x 480 ... OK
- 640 x 576 ... OK
- 1280 x 720 ... OK
- 1280 x 720 ... OK
- 1920 x 1080 ... OK
- 2048 x 1556 ... OK
- 4096 x 2160 ... OK

### MP4

- 640 x 480 ... OK
- 640 x 576 ... OK
- 1280 x 720 ... OK
- 1280 x 720 ... OK
- 1920 x 1080 ... OK
- 2048 x 1556 ... MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE
- 4096 x 2160 ... MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE

And here is my code.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
TIFF *out;
IMFSinkWriter   *pWriter = NULL;
IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeOut = NULL;   
IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeIn = NULL;   
DWORD           streamIndex;     

hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(filename, NULL, NULL, &pWriter);

// Set the output media type.
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut);   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);     
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  if (exportMethod == ExportFormatWAV) {
    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_WVC1);
  }
  else if (exportMethod == ExportFormatMP4) {
    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);   
  }
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 12 * 1000 * 1000); // 12M   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, m_width, m_height);   // e.g. 4096 x 2160
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, m_fps * 100, 100);   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = pWriter->AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, &streamIndex);   
}

// Set the input media type.
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn);   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  if (exportMethod == ExportFormatWAV) {
    hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB24);   
  }
  else if (exportMethod == ExportFormatMP4) {
    hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32);     // Because H264 requires
  }
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, m_width, m_height);   // e.g. 4096 x 2160
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, m_fps * 100, 100);   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);   
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = pWriter->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, NULL);   // This line returns MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE
}

// Tell the sink writer to start accepting data.
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
  hr = pWriter->BeginWriting();
}
```

I want to export a large sized video of **MP4** as well.
Does anyone know a solution against this problem?

References
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819477(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819476(v=vs.85).aspx

### Oct 13th 2015

Same question has already posted msdn.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac5b71e4-e94a-4d18-bc92-8b44fa5280b6/the-max-resolution-for-mp4h264-encoder

Comment: I guess you are hitting the limits of stock H.264 encoder - in Windows 7 it is limited to Main profile and perhaps certain level, in Windows 8 the limitations are relaxed however might still be insufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Certainly i was testing it with Win7. But i want to make it work on Win7 as well. If i want to generate large size mp4 file in any platforms, what library should i use?

Comment: There are other H.264 encoders: Intel Media SDK, libx264, MainConcept - perhaps some of them are more appropriate for your needs. The advantage of MS encoder is the fact that it's free and built into operating system.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to use the library.

Answer (score 1):

Media Foundation's [MPEG-4 File Sink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763) has no resolution restrictions. It multiplexes already encoded data and is not sensitive to video resolution.

If/when you, however, are encoding H.264 context, the encoders typically do have the limitations. For example, Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600's Intel® Quick Sync Video H.264 Encoder MFT can produce 4096 x 4096 H.264 content, and MP4 sink writes it correctly to file.

In your case you are likely to hit resolution limit in encoder, and since encoder rejects unsupported resolution with generic error code, you don't have anything more helpful than `MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE`. You might have better luck with an alternate encoder.

Comment: By "alternate encoder", do you mean selecting a different MFT within Media Foundation? (e.g. in the case where multiple H264 encoding MFTs are installed?) If yes, how?

Or do you mean switching away from Media Foundation entirely?

Comment: @LTR: Within sink writer your flexibility is to use best (hardware when available) or non-hardware (stock software) encoder only. However, you can use compression MFT outside of wink writer and feed already compressed video - sink writer will accept this to write as is.