# Resolution Issue when create .mp4 video file from camera streaming using SourceReader

Tags: c++, video, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I'm developing the Window Desktop Camera application using SourceReader technique.I have completed Video streaming and still capture.

Now, I'm working on to capturing an .mp4 video file from USB camera. I'm able to capture video file for the following resolutions: 640 x 480,1280 x 720 and 1920 X 1080. 
I have encountered an issue when changing the video resolution higher than 1920 x 1080 and call SetInputMediaType for the IMFSinkWriter object returns an HRESULT error code 0xc00d36b.

I used video subtype for encoding : MFVideoFormat_H264

Is there any other subtype available for encoding .mp4 file other than MFVideoFormat_H264?

Why cant i capturing an .mp4 file higher than FULL HD resolution? Am i missing anything to encode the video file? If yes, please provide me some guidelines to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The likely bottleneck is the maximal resolution supported by video encoder. You are presumably using the encoder implicitly as a part of Sink Writer. Sink Writer on its own does not limit the resolution, but if encoder is unable to handle specific media type then encoding is impossible. Specifically, in Windows 7 resolution is (or might be) limited to 1920x1088.

Also, you lost one digit from the error code.

See also:

- [IMFSinkWriter can't export a large size video of mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030620/imfsinkwriter-cant-export-a-large-size-video-of-mp4/36386821#36386821)
- [The max resolution for mp4(h264) encoder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/ac5b71e4-e94a-4d18-bc92-8b44fa5280b6/the-max-resolution-for-mp4h264-encoder?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment)

Comment: Thank you for your advice and pointed me in missing one digit in error code. I was working in Windows 8. Why am i receiving this error?. In both the links, they pointed to use MPEG-4 sink and i will try to use this sink and get back to you if i face anyerror. I have one more question to you, Is there anyway to find out what encoder actually using sink writer when capture a video file?

Comment: You can access encoders using [`IMFSinkWriterEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448060) but the easiest is to start with disabling hardware encoder and forcing software encoder using [`MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375765) attribute. This way you know it's should be H.264 encoder.

Comment: Thank you Roman. I will this flag to check the current encode used by sink writer. I used MPEG-4 File Sink to capture an video file but still i received the same error which i mentioned in the previous query. Please use the dropbox link to view my code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1pnf2rhtc83n9x/MPEG4-Sink_Code_StackOverflow.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Roman gave a great answer, but just to add on the topic of other codecs - if you check [MPEG-4 File Sink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN you see that it mentions MJPG support as well (even though not clear if it's only available from Windows 8 or it simply has been improved in Windows 8), so you should be able to use `MFVideoFormat_MJPG` as well. I assume that should not have any size limitations, but of course the size of the resulting .mp4 file will grow drasticly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have used MPEG-4 File Sink to capture higher resolution video but still I'm facing same error which I mentioned in earlier post.Herewith attached my sample code in this link for your reference: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1pnf2rhtc83n9x/MPEG4-Sink_Code_StackOverflow.txt?dl=0. I'm very beginner to media foundation.Past one week I'm struggling with this issue. Please provide some ideas if my code is wrong. Thank you once again.

Comment: There is a limitation to capture a .mp4 file in windows 8. It allows to capture till Full HD resolution but we able to capture till Ultra HD in windows 10. Thank you for your valuable comments.