# Capturing video when screen resolution is above 1920x1080

Tags: c++, windows, video, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to write a Win32 c++ program which uses [Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-foundation-programming-guide), for capturing [mp4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) videos of the desktop. I found that on a PC with screen resolution of over 1920x1080, capturing fails. The failure is following a call to **[SetInputMediaType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsinkwriter-setinputmediatype)**() which returns error 0xc00d36b4 (The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object)

Any solution?

```
HRESULT InitializeDirect3D9(IDirect3DDevice9** ppDevice, IDirect3DSurface9** ppSurface, UINT32& uiWidth, UINT32& uiHeight) 
{

IDirect3D9* d3d = NULL;

d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

if (d3d == NULL)
    return E_POINTER;

D3DDISPLAYMODE mode;
HRESULT hr = d3d->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &mode);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    SafeRelease(&d3d);
    return hr;
}

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS parameters = { 0 };

parameters.Windowed = TRUE;
parameters.BackBufferCount = 1;
uiHeight = parameters.BackBufferHeight = mode.Height;
uiWidth = parameters.BackBufferWidth = mode.Width;
parameters.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
parameters.hDeviceWindow = NULL;

hr = d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, NULL, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &parameters, ppDevice);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    SafeRelease(&d3d);
    return hr;
}

hr = (*ppDevice)->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(mode.Width, mode.Height, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, ppSurface, nullptr);

SafeRelease(&d3d);

return hr;
}

HRESULT SGCaptureDecktopVideo::InitializeSinkWriter(std::wstring VideoPath, IMFSinkWriter **ppWriter, DWORD *pStreamIndex, const UINT32 uiWidth, const UINT32 uiHeight)
{
*ppWriter = NULL;
*pStreamIndex = NULL;

IMFSinkWriter   *pSinkWriter = NULL;
IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeOut = NULL;
IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeIn = NULL;
DWORD           streamIndex;

HRESULT hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(VideoPath.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &pSinkWriter);

// Set the output media type.
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VIDEO_ENCODING_FORMAT);
}
�
void vidThread(vidThreadArgs *args)
{

WriteLogFile(L"Thread started");
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    WriteLogFile(L"CoInitializeEx - success");

    hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"MFStartup - success");

        UINT32 uiWidth = 0;
        UINT32 uiHeight = 0;

        IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice = NULL;
        IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface = NULL;


        hr = myVideoRecorder.InitializeDirect3D9(&pDevice, &pSurface, uiWidth, uiHeight);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            WriteLogFile(L"InitializeDirect3D9 - success");

            IMFSinkWriter *pSinkWriter = NULL;
            DWORD stream;

            hr = myVideoRecorder.InitializeSinkWriter(myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VideoPath, &pSinkWriter, &stream, uiWidth, uiHeight);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {

                WriteLogFile(L"InitializeSinkWriter - success");

                LONGLONG rtStart = 0;
                unsigned long long int frameCounter = 0;

                while (true)
                {

                    hr = myVideoRecorder.WriteFrame(pDevice, pSurface, pSinkWriter, stream, rtStart, uiWidth, uiHeight);
                    frameCounter++;

                    if (FAILED(hr))
                    {

                        WriteLogFile(L"Internal error %d Frame %d\n",
                            GetLastError(), frameCounter);

                        break;
                    }

                    rtStart += myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION;
                    if (bStopRecording)
                    {
                        WriteLogFile(L"Finalizing recording of file %s. Frame %llu",
                            myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VideoPath.c_str(),
                            frameCounter);

                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
            else
            {

                DWORD error = GetLastError();
                WriteLogFile(L"failed here. Error %d\n", error);
            }

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pSinkWriter->Finalize();
            }

            SafeRelease(&pSinkWriter);
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLogFile(L"InitializeDirect3D9 - failed Error %d",GetLastError());
            result = STATUS_ERROR_INIT_DIRECT3D9;
        }
        SafeRelease(&pDevice);
        SafeRelease(&pSurface);
        MFShutdown();
        WriteLogFile(L"MFShutDown");
    }
    else
    {
        result = STATUS_ERROR_MFSSTARTUP;
        WriteLogFile(L"MFStartup failed");

    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
else
{
    result = STATUS_ERROR_COINITILIZE;
    WriteLogFile(L"CoInitilize - failed Error %d", GetLastError());
}



HRESULT WriteFrame(IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice, IDirect3DSurface9*
pSurface, IMFSinkWriter* pWriter, DWORD streamIndex, const
LONGLONG& rtStart, const UINT32 uiWidth, const UINT32 uiHeight){

    HRESULT hr = pDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);

    if(FAILED(hr)){
        return hr;
    }

    D3DLOCKED_RECT rc;
    hr = pSurface->LockRect(&rc, NULL, 0);

    if(FAILED(hr)){
        return hr;
    }

    IMFSample *pSample = NULL;
    IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;

    const LONG cbWidth = 4 * uiWidth;
    const DWORD cbBuffer = cbWidth * uiHeight;

    BYTE *pData = NULL;

    // Create a new memory buffer.
    hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(cbBuffer, &pBuffer);

    // Lock the buffer and copy the video frame to the buffer.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pData, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

#ifdef REVERSE_IMAGE
        for(int i = 0, j = uiHeight - 1; i < uiHeight; i++, j--)
            for(int k = 0; k < cbWidth; k++)
                    pData[(i * cbWidth) + k] = ((BYTE*)rc.pBits)[(j *
cbWidth) + k];
#else
        hr = MFCopyImage(pData, cbWidth, (BYTE*)rc.pBits, rc.Pitch,
cbWidth, uiHeight);
#endif
    }

    if(pBuffer){
        pBuffer->Unlock();
    }

    // Set the data length of the buffer.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pBuffer->SetCurrentLength(cbBuffer);
    }

    // Create a media sample and add the buffer to the sample.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = MFCreateSample(&pSample);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer);
    }

    // Set the time stamp and the duration.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pSample->SetSampleTime(rtStart);
    }

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pSample->SetSampleDuration(VIDEO_FRAME_DURATION);
    }

    // Send the sample to the Sink Writer.
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pWriter->WriteSample(streamIndex, pSample);
    }

    hr = pSurface->UnlockRect();

    SafeRelease(&pSample);
    SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
    return hr;
}
```

Code was tested on 5 different machines, all with Windows 10 x64, and found out that if I store the values of *uiWidth* and *uiHeight* in a log file, just before the following line:

```
hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, uiWidth, uiHeight);
```

The code works perfectly when their values are bellow 1220 and 1080, and they get 0 sized video files when either (or both) of these values exceed 1220x1080.

Update:
I am also publishing **InitializeSinkWriter**(). At Step 17, SetInputMediaType() fails with error c00d36b4.

```
HRESULT SGCaptureDecktopVideo::InitializeSinkWriter(std::wstring VideoPath, IMFSinkWriter **ppWriter, DWORD *pStreamIndex, const UINT32 uiWidth, const UINT32 uiHeight)
{
    *ppWriter = NULL;
    *pStreamIndex = NULL;

    IMFSinkWriter   *pSinkWriter = NULL;
    IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeOut = NULL;
    IMFMediaType    *pMediaTypeIn = NULL;
    DWORD           streamIndex;

    // Step 1 - MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(VideoPath.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &pSinkWriter);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 1 - MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL() failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 2 - MFCreateMediaType
    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeOut);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)==0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 2 - MFCreateMediaType() failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 3 - SetGUID (MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE)
    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)==0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 3 - SetGUID (MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 4 - SetGUID (MF_MT_SUBTYPE)
    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VIDEO_ENCODING_FORMAT);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 4 - SetGUID (MF_MT_SUBTYPE) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 5 - SetUINT32 (MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE)
    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VIDEO_BIT_RATE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 5 - SetUINT32 (MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 6 - SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE)
    hr = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 6 - SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 7 - MFSetAttributeSize
    WriteLogFile(L"w %d h %d",uiWidth, uiHeight);
    hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, uiWidth, uiHeight);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 7 - MFSetAttributeSize() failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 8 - MFSetAttributeRatio - MF_MT_FRAME_RATE
    hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 8 - MFSetAttributeRatio(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 9 - MFSetAttributeRatio - MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO
    hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 9 - MFSetAttributeRatio(MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 10 - AddStream
    hr = pSinkWriter->AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, &streamIndex);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 10 - AddStream() failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 11 - MFCreateMediaType
    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaTypeIn);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0 || pMediaTypeIn==NULL)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 11 - MFCreateMediaType() failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 12 - SetGUID (MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE)
    hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 12 - SetGUID (MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 13 - SetGUID (MF_MT_SUBTYPE)
    hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VIDEO_INPUT_FORMAT);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 13 - SetGUID (MF_MT_SUBTYPE) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 13 - SetUINT32 (MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE)
    hr = pMediaTypeIn->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"SetUINT32 (MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE). %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 14 - SMFSetAttributeSize
    hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, uiWidth, uiHeight);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 14 - MFSetAttributeSize() failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 15 - MFSetAttributeRatio(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE)
    hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, myVideoRecorder.CaptureParams.VIDEO_FPS, 1);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 15 - MFSetAttributeRatio(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 16 - MFSetAttributeRatio(MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO)
    hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 16 - MFSetAttributeRatio(MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO) failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    // Step 17 - SetInputMediaType
    hr = pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, pMediaTypeIn, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 17 - SetInputMediaType() failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    // Step 18 - BeginWriting() Tell the sink writer to start accepting data.
    hr = pSinkWriter->BeginWriting();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) == 0)
    {
        WriteLogFile(L"Step 18 - BeginWriting() failed. %x", hr);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    // Return the pointer to the caller.
    WriteLogFile(L"Success");

    *ppWriter = pSinkWriter;
    (*ppWriter)->AddRef();
    *pStreamIndex = streamIndex;

cleanup:;
    SafeRelease(&pSinkWriter);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeOut);
    SafeRelease(&pMediaTypeIn);
    return hr;
}
```

I still get an error in this part on machines with a higher resolution. CreateDevice() fails with error 0x7E.

```
D3DDISPLAYMODE mode;

HRESULT hr = d3d->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &mode);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    WriteLogFile(L"GetAdapterDisplayMode() failed. Error =%x", GetLastError());
    SafeRelease(&d3d);
    return hr;
}
WriteLogFile(L"Fetched mode. Width=%d Height=%d", mode.Width, mode.Height);
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS parameters = { 0 };

parameters.Windowed = TRUE;
parameters.BackBufferCount = 1;
uiHeight = parameters.BackBufferHeight = mode.Height;
uiWidth = parameters.BackBufferWidth = mode.Width;
parameters.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
parameters.hDeviceWindow = NULL;

hr = d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, NULL, D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &parameters, ppDevice);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    WriteLogFile(L"CreateDevice failed. Error =%x",GetLastError());
    SafeRelease(&d3d);
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about how (or what) fails? What error messages do you get? Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez I updated my question with part of the code. Basically, when the screen resolution is higher, video files are created with size 0.

Comment: That's really useful information! Could you the part about video files with size zero to the question itself?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez I can however the problem is that WriteFrame fails so since I opened the target video file for writing, it will have a size 0, since no data was written

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger to find where it fails?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez see updated question

Comment: @RetiredNinja please see updated question and source code: upon calling InitilizeDirect3D9() it fails with error 1168

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I updated my question accordingly. Error is in InitikizeDirect3D9() which brings 1168 when calling GetLastError().

Comment: That is InitilizeDirect3D9()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bottleneck is resolution support in video encoder.

Video encoders typically have limits on resolutions, however the limits vary. Maximal safe resolution widely supported is 1920x1088. In your case you are probably using Microsoft's software encoder. I think some time in past [MSDN documetnation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-encoder) mentioned directly the maximal resolution, however this information is not currently present there.

There is no way to identify maximal supported resolution reliably and it mostly looks like an API design flaw.

For the record, Windows 10 Version 1903 (May 2019 Update) is shipped with software H.264 video encoder capable to encode at least 3840x2160 video.

See also:

- [IMFSinkWriter can't export a large size video of mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36386821/868014)
- [The max resolution for mp4(h264) encoder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/ac5b71e4-e94a-4d18-bc92-8b44fa5280b6/the-max-resolution-for-mp4h264-encoder?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the error handling in this code is problematic. If will simply skip operations if anything fails, but never actually reports any failures. Almost certainly one of the API calls is failing, and you need to actually report the error at that point and display the hex value (easiest to read and look up) of `hr`, and bail.  So you need to fix up the error reporting and tell us which API is failing, and what the result is.

As to why it could be failing, codecs like MP4 have encoding profiles, and they prefer to work with certain resolutions or bitrates. It's possible that the higher resolution exceeded the limit for that profile, or it is a non-standard resolution that MP4 doesn't support (or have a profile for). Or that the profile is bitrate-limited, and the higher resolution requested exceeds the bitrate available.

Comment: See updated question and code. Failure is when calling MFSetAttributeSize()

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out that *uiWidth* and *uiHeight* can’t exceed 1920x1080, so they need to be adjusted before calling MFSetAttributeSize().

```
INT32 outWidth = uiWidth;
    INT32 outHeight = uiHeight;

    if (uiWidth > 1920 || uiHeight > 1080)
    {
        outWidth = 1920;
        outHeight = 1080;
    }
hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, outWidth, outHeight);
```

That apparently solved the problem on computers where the resolution was higher than 1920x1080.